# Easily controlled color LCD for hobby projects?

Tags: avr, lcd, display

I'm looking for some not too expensive, easy to control color graphics LCD I can use for various hobby projects, along with an AVR microcontroller or maybe an ARM in the future. The cheaper the better, but I want to be able to either control it with a serial connection, or a low-speed parallel connection. Some LCDs require multiple MHz parallel control signals to drive each pixel individually, I probably can't manage that with a single AVR. This unfortunately rules out super cheap LCDs like replacement Nintendo DS LCDs or whatever. Recommendations on LCDs that you've personally used & liked will be especially appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What resolution? What do you consider low-cost?

Comment: Don't have a specific resolution needs, I'd like to know some options. As for low cost, the cheaper the better...but I'd say the range is $20-$50.

Answer (score 4):

[This LCD assembly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11062) works with serial commands and is only about $35 [USD].  There are other options as well, but even once you get past the command set, interfacing to small LCDs physically is difficult due to the FPC connectors they use.  If that is not a problem, you might find more variety with low cost color displays from [Newhaven Display International](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/).  I've used two of their products so far.  Digikey carries some of them, but some seem to have a large minimum order quantity, so you might have to order directly from newhaven.

Comment: Which have you used from Newhaven, their color TFT displays? They look interesting, though it might require a good number of I/O pins, but still usable (8-bit paralell + a few more for control signals)

Comment: I've used the NHD-2.4-240320YF-CTX#-T-1-ND and the NHD-C128128BZ-FSW-GBW-ND.  Unfortunately they both require 16 bit interfaces (the data sheets, unfortunately, are misleading) so they won't be easy to drive directly from the arduino, but a serial in parallel out chip could be used.  They don't require high speed updates, and they are reasonably nice displays.